# Angular JS index of selected TD

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table

```
<tr ng-repeat="car in cars | filter:search:strict | orderBy: 'Type'">
    <td>{{car.Type}}</td>
    <td>{{car.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{car.Year}}</td>
</tr>
```

Can I get a car's `index`: a number which represents a place in cars array?
Currently, it is not in right order, because of `orderBy` filter.

Answer (score 1):

Do the sorting in a controller. Then place the sorted items into a cars array. Then do

```
<tr ng-repeat="car in cars track by $index">
  <td>{{$index}}</td>
  <td>{{car.Type}}</td>
  <td>{{car.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{car.Year}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just call [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) with your car object to get its original index

```
<tr ng-repeat="car in cars | filter:search:strict | orderBy: 'Type'" ng-click="someFunc(cars.indexOf(car))">
    <td>{{car.Type}}</td>
    <td>{{car.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{car.Year}}</td>
</tr>
```